# How do I drop items in Divinity: Original Sin 2?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

So, I played Divinity on PC, don't recall having any issues throwing the teleport pyramids around.
But I can't for the life of me figure out how to throw the dang pyramids.  While in my hot bar, there is no right or left click context menu.  If I drag them off the bar and release they just go back to my inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop items from your inventory, not from your hotbar.